# $ \pi(n) > \frac{n}{22 \ln(n)} $ simple proof?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-writing, prime-numbers, alternative-proof

What is the easiest way to show that

$$ n > 2 $$

$$ \pi(n) > \frac{n}{2 \ln(n)} $$

Where $\pi(n)$ is the prime counting function.

I read a proof of the PNT with the zeta function but this statement is much weaker !!

What is the shortest proof ? 
The simplest ?
The most elementary ?

Do we use results from Mertens ? ( $\Pi ( 1 - 1/p) $ or $ \sum 1/p $ )
Do we need to use results of Mertens ?
Do we need to estimate $\sum \ln(p) $ ?

How about the even weaker

$$ \pi(n) > \frac{n}{22 \ln(n)} $$

Is that even easier ? Or not ?

Comment: The PNT doesn't prove your two lower bounds for all $n>2,$ so it is not weaker, because $\pi(n)\sim \frac{n}{\log n}$ doesn't say anything for small $n,$ only for $n$ large enough.

Comment: @Thomas yes it is a bit different. I thought about it after I posted it. So strictly formally yes. But it “ feels “ weaker , where weaker is an informal word. Thank you.

Comment: The easiest way is probably a variant of Chebyshev's way, using $T(x) - 2T(x/2)$ instead of Chebyshev's $T(x) - T(x/2) - T(x/3) - T(x/5) + T(x/30)$ (where $T(x) = \sum_{n \leqslant x} \log n$).

Comment: Daniel's method is very elementary (for $n$ even) : $$\log(n/2)( \pi(n)-\pi(n/2))\le \log n! - 2\log (n/2)! \le \psi(n) \le \log n( \pi(n) +2 n^{1/2}) $$ and by induction $\log n! - 2\log (n/2)!  = n \log 4+O(\log n)$, that's all we obtained $\pi(n) \in \frac{n}{\log n} [a,b]$. Morally $a\approx 1,b\approx 1/2$. Better $a,b$ can be obtained from better $\log n!$ approximations to $\log n(\pi(n)-\pi(n/2))$, but it is not useful.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment:

In Section 4.5 of Apostol's *Introduction to Analytic Number Theory* (page 82-84), we have

> **Theorem 4.6** *For every integer $n\ge2$, we have*
>
> $${1\over6}{n\over\log n}\lt\pi(n)\lt6{n\over\log n}$$

The proof is elementary. This takes care of the OP's question with $22$ in the denominator, but leaves open the question whether there's a simple proof if you replace Apostol's $6$ with a $2$. Apostol does, however, introduce the theorem saying, "Although better inequalities can be obtained with greater effort (see [60]) the following theorem is of interest because of the elementary nature of its proof." Reference [60] is:

> Rosser, J. Barkley, and Schoenfeld, Lowell (1962) Approximate formulas
>   for some functions of prime number theory. *Illinois J. Math.,
>   6*:69-94; *MR* 25, #1139.

Comment: I have a copy of that paper I made over 40 years ago. Maybe I should scan it in.

Comment: @martycohen, not necessary: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1255631807

Comment: Thank you very much. It would be interesting to take fewer terms of that Chebychev expansion and see what the bonds are.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the proof given by Dusard in his thesis is the best one:
we have
$$
\pi(x)  \ge \frac{x}{\log(x)}\left( 1+\frac{1}{\log(x)}+\frac{1.8}{\log^2(x)}\right)
$$
for all real $x\ge 32299$, and this bound is sharp. For all $x\ge x_0$  we obtain the bounds in general, and then we test for $\frac{1}{2}$ or $\frac{1}{22}$ for all $x\le x_0$ by a direct computation.

There is also an elementary proof by Chebychev, see [here](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_23_cheby_error.pdf), with the variant Daniel is suggesting above. But it is also a bit tedious to do this and a general results perhaps seems to be useful then.

Comment: But does that ( your second solution based on Daniels comment ) not reduce the problem to the restatement in terms of Chevy T(n) ? As for the Dusart problem , that is much stronger and more complicated than PNT imho. So overkill ? Not as simple as I wanted at first sight.

Comment: The restatement in terms of $T(n)$ is elementary but not so handy to do. And since you don't want to do it for each such question, Dusart's result is really useful.

Comment: Yes Dusart is useful. But more powerful. Since my question seems to ask for a simpler fact , I suspect a simpler proof to exist. Simpler than using Dusart. Besides Dusarts proof is not so simple imho. Lots of respect for Mr Dusart though :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ might help answer the question :

[$f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + f(x/4) + ... = x$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{\pi(n)} = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724917/fx-fx-2-fx-3-fx-4-x-and-lim-n-to-infty-fracfn/4745052#4745052)

In particular combining the answer I gave and the related asymptotic to the harmonic sum

$$ H(x) = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + ... 1/x = \ln(x) - 1$$

Although the details are not yet clear to me.

The idea is to relate $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

An easy proof of conjecture $A$ (not using the PNT) would be very useful.
But maybe it is not required.

Just my 50 cent.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for integer $n$ larger than $82$.

We desire to prove the PNT up to a multiplicative constant.
This is much easier than proving the PNT and was in fact done by Chebyshev(first) and others.

using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate

We need the following two lemmas from that page.

**Lemma 1:** ${2n \choose n} > \frac{4^n}{2n+1}$.

**Lemma 2:** The greatest power $R(p, n)$ of a prime $p$ dividing ${2n \choose n}$ satisfies $p^{R(p, n)} \le 2n$.

From these two lemmas it follows that

$$\frac{4^n}{2n+1} < {2n \choose n} \le (2n)^{\pi(2n)}$$

which is a contradiction for large $n$ if $\pi(2n)$ is bounded. This gets us within a constant of the PNT:

$$\pi(2n) \ge \frac{n \log 4 - \log (2n+1)}{\log 2n}.$$