# $f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + f(x/4) + ... = x$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{\pi(n)} = 1$?

Tags: limits, number-theory, prime-numbers, functional-equations, alternative-proof

$$f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + f(x/4) + ... = x$$

$$f(n) < \pi(n+1)$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{\pi(n)} = 1$$

where $\pi(n)$ is the prime counting function.

My mentor more or less wrote that when he was around $12$ yo.

If you use the Riemann zeta function $\zeta(s)$ to prove the PNT and you know the easy $f(x) < \frac{x}{\ln(x)-1}$ (easy to show for large $x$ at least) then with some little extra work you can prove the two statements at least for large $x$ or large $n$.

But how about proving it directly ?
What if we did not know that $\pi(n)$ is about $= \frac{x}{\ln(x)-1}$ ?
What if we do not use the zeta function nor complex dynamics ?

Is this related to one of those elementary proofs of the prime number theorem ?

How does one even come up with the idea of the equation above ??
What is the logic behind it ?

Do not confuse with the similar looking

$$Li(x) + Li(x^{1/2}) + Li(x^{1/3}) + ...$$

you often see in number theory, this is not the one.

And it is also not this one

$$g(x) + g(x)/2 + g(x)/3 + g(x)/4 + ... = x$$

Because that one gives about $g(n) = \frac{n}{H_n}$ where H_n is the n th harmonic number, what is a weak version of the PNT.

It also does not follow from the 3 theorems of Mertens nor does it resemble anything I ever read.

I am not looking for sharp asymptotics for $f(x)$ here, that is not the question here.
(although I will probably start a new topic about that soon)

Any ideas ?

Btw this function is even more mysterious when you think about it :

For example

$$f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + f(x/4) + ... = x$$

substitute $x$ to $x/2$

$$f(x/2) + f(x/4) + f(x/6) + f(x/8) + f(x/10) + ... = x/2$$

This implies that

$$f(x) + f(x/3) + f(x/5) + f(x/7) + f(x/9) + ... = x/2$$

and thus

$$f(x/2) + f(x/4) + f(x/6) + f(x/8) + f(x/10) + ... = f(x) + f(x/3) + f(x/5) + f(x/7) + f(x/9) + ... $$

and

$$f(f(x) + f(x/3) + f(x/5) + f(x/7) + f(x/9) + ...) = f(f(x/2) + f(x/4) + f(x/6) + f(x/8) + f(x/10) + ...) = f(x/2)$$

and similar identities can be constructed.
Imo very much like series multisection, fractals and self-referential things.

But getting series expansions for it that are defined everywhere is hard.

Does $f$ need to be continu ?

Maybe we should relax the equation and write

$$f(n) + f(n/2) + f(n/3) + f(n/4) + ...= n$$

and the divisions get rounded or so.

Or maybe we should truncate the ellipsis (...) somehow.

But that still does not answer my questions.

---

***edit***

My mentor told me this

$$\pi(x) + \pi(x/2) + \pi(x/3) + ... > x$$

if we take enough terms and if the following is true

$$\pi(x/a) > \frac{\pi(x)}{a}$$

(conjecture A)

It then follows that

$$f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + ... = x$$

implies that $f(x) < \pi(x)$

Conjecture A might have a name, it is a weaker version of the second hardy-littlewood conjecture :

$$\pi(x+y) - \pi(x) < \pi(y) + 1$$

Conjecture A makes sense for large $x$ and small $a$ for sure if we use a sharp version of the prime number theorem somewhat like the good asymptotic

$$\frac{x}{\ln(x) - 1 + \frac{1}{\ln(x)}}$$

But I am unsure if conjecture A has been proven.

Again this might be overkill but it is another way of thinking about it.

see :

[$f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + ... = x$ and conjecture A : $\pi(x/a) > \frac{\pi(x)}{a}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728147/fx-fx-2-fx-3-x-and-conjecture-a-pix-a-frac-pix)

---

***edit***

A similar looking idea seems to have occured here on page 8 :

[http://www.math.columbia.edu/~goldfeld/ErdosSelbergDispute.pdf](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Egoldfeld/ErdosSelbergDispute.pdf)

although that is an integral instead of a sum.

I wanted to mention it.
Maybe it has value to someone.

---

Comment: See also : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724921/tx-tx-2-tx-3-tx-4-0-implies-tx-tx-2tx-3tx-4

Comment: $ \infty \cdot f(0) = 0 \implies f(0) = 0$

Comment: @hellofriends ?

Comment: put $x=0$ in the equation

Comment: if you use $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(\frac x{np}) = \frac xp$ for any $p$ prime, you may get something like the prime sieve algorithm.

Comment: also, it is easy to see that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$ at least.

Comment: @hellofriends easy to see it is continu at $x=0$ ?? If I consider the ellipsis as neverending ( going over all integers ) Then if $f(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$ , this implies ( for the sum to converge ) that $f ' (0) = 0$ since the harmonic series diverges.
On the other hand if I take the derivative at both sides I get (by the above) $ x' =  f '(x) + f ' (x/2) + f ' (x/3) + ...$ what implies 
$1 = 0 + 0 + 0 + ...$ Contradiction.
So the derivative is hard to define at zero. 
Therefore continu at zero is nontrivial to me.

Comment: I think it would be nice of you to pinpoint what are the domain and the codomain of $f$. Do you agree with me that $f(0) = 0$? Now if the $\sum f(\frac xn)$ always converges to $x$, then we must assume that $f(\frac xn)$ converges to zero. Otherwise the sum will diverge and you won't have the derivative you wanted. As $\frac xn \rightarrow 0$, we can say for sure that $f$ is continuous at zero. No?

Comment: @hellofriends That reasoning is flawed. Let $f$ be a discontinuous solution to the cauchy functional equation $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$. Then $f(x/n) = f(x)/n \to 0$, but $f$ is discontinuous at every point. I think you need some sort of uniformity of $f(x/n) \to 0$ in $x$ to conclude that $f$ is continuous at 0. It might be possible to do that using the full equation in the OP, but just knowing that $f(x/n) \to 0$ isn't enough.

Comment: @S.C. you're correct. My bad.

Comment: The idea $f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + ... + f(2*) = x$ has occured where $2*$ is close to $2$.
This was posted by the inventor elsewhere ( not on MSE ). Just saying.

Comment: I think a natural way of arriving at the equation is by inspection of $\sum\pi(x/k)$ as k is increased.

Comment: perhaps related ?? 

(see the edit) 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745073/about-a-counterexample-for-an-integral-functional-equation-in-number-theory

Comment: Where did your mentor receive his Mathematics training when he was a teenager? This result that he proved makes me feel so small.

Comment: @KamalSaleh I did not give any formal proofs. Surely this is outside of the books or educational system, in particular around the age of $12$. No need to feel small my friend.

Comment: So your mentor didn't prove this result when he first found it?

Comment: @KamalSaleh It is a long time ago. He was still young. Some papers are lost. I do not know. He did not write a proof at the same page. I talked about it with him but he is unsure. He recalled it being very intuitive. He was not very into math at that time, it was just a "game " or "thing " he was good at.

Comment: ...He concluded that the number of primes $\pi(x) > x^v$ for large $x$ and any fixed  $0< v < 1$. And he became convinced of the infinitude of prime twins.  Im convinced most stuff only existed in his head and were not explicitly written. It was not written for an audience but more like a diary or note or so.

Comment: @KamalSaleh but If you are looking for impressive teenage conjectures he made , this one personally impressed me alot : 

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/322240/why-is-sup-f-n-inf-f-m-frac54

Answer (score 1):

here is a some what formalization of my thoughts

$$f(x) + f(\frac{x}{p_n}) + f(\frac{x}{p_{n+1}}) + f(\frac{x}{b_i}) + ... = \frac x{a_n} \tag{1}$$

where $p_n$ is the $n-$th prime number, $p_1=2,p_2=3,...$

$b_i$ is either a prime number after $p_n$ or a multiple of some prime number $p_n,p_{n+1},p_{n+2},...$ such that no prime before $p_{n}$ divides those multiples i.e. the multiples left only have factors $p_k$ with $k \geq n$. The classic Eratosthenes' prime sieve.

for $n=1$ we have the classic relation, which leads to $a_1=1$.

Let's apply $x \rightarrow \frac x{p_n}$ on $(1)$:

$$f(\frac{x}{p_n}) + f(\frac{x}{p_n^2}) + f(\frac{x}{p_{n+1}p_n}) + f(\frac{x}{b_ip_n}) + ... = \frac x{p_na_n}$$

we covered all the multiples of $p_n$ that were in $(1)$ so:

$$f(x) + f(\frac{x}{p_n}) + f(\frac{x}{p_{n+1}}) + f(\frac{x}{b_i}) + ...  -[f(\frac{x}{p_n}) + f(\frac{x}{p_n^2}) + f(\frac{x}{p_{n+1}p_n}) + ...]= \frac x{a_n} -\frac x{p_na_n}$$

so

$$f(x) + f(\frac x{p_{n+1}}) + f(\frac x{p_{n+2}}) + f(\frac{x}{c_j}) +... = \frac x{a_n} -\frac x{p_na_n} = \frac x{a_n}(1- \frac1{p_n}) = \frac x{a_{n+1}}$$

so we have:

$$\frac1{a_{n+1}} = \frac1{a_n}(1-\frac1{p_n}) \implies \frac1{a_{k+1}} = \prod_{n=1}^k (1-\frac1{p_n}) \iff \\ a_k = \frac1{\prod_{n=1}^{k-1}(1-\frac1{p_n})}$$

which I believe to be correct. Interestingly, we have the Euler Identity for Riemann's zeta function:

$$\zeta (s) = \prod_p \frac1{1-p^{-s}}$$

which goes to show that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} a_n = \infty$. Which is interesting:

$$f(x) + \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} (f(\frac x{p_n}) + f(\frac{x}{b_n,i}) + ...) = 0$$

Comment: Thank you for explaining your thoughts.
But it is not yet clear to me. Maybe the raw idea but how - for instance - do you avoid MINUS $f(x/c)$ terms ? And how do we arrive at $\sum f(x/n°$ over all poisive integers $n$ ? Mertens third theorem is related to the estimate $x \prod (1 - 1/p_n) $ but this $f$ does better I think. Not sure how to explain that then ?

Comment: it is nice that you mentioned Mertens' theorem because the result I arrived above proves that $f$ must change its sign. I do not have a plan to extend to all naturals, but my guts tell me we should try to bound the sum $\sum f(\frac x{b_{i,n}})$ using the other inequalities we got. If we can figure out a limit to these sums, the problem is done.

Comment: $a_n$ could depend on $x$. Check if its OK with your answer. I modified my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @Balajisb mine can't, yours can. Mine absorbs the original expression.

Comment: Interesting. If possible, please explain it in the answer. Only if its possible.

Comment: @Balajisb very simple, $n=1$ is the original expression and my operations don't make $x$ appear.

Comment: Thanks +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

A property:

$$f(x) + f(x/m) + f(x/m^2) + f(x/m^3) + \ldots  =  x \times a_m(x)$$

$$f(x/m) + f(x/m^2) + f(x/m^3) + f(x/m^4) + \ldots  =  \frac{x}{m} a_m(x/m)$$
Hence,
$$f(x) = x\left(a_m(x) - \frac{a_m(x/m)}{m}\right)$$

We also have,
$$f(x/m) = x\left(\frac{a_m(x/m)}{m} - \frac{a_m(x/m^2)}{m^2}\right)$$

Hence $$x a_m(x) = f(x) + f(x/m) + f(x/m^2) + \ldots $$ $$= x \left(a_m(x) - \frac{a_m(x/m)}{m}\right) + x\left(\frac{a_m(x/m)}{m} - \frac{a_m(x/m^2)}{m^2}\right) + \ldots $$ $$= x\left(a_m(x) - \lim_j \frac{a_m(x/m^j)}{m^j}\right)$$

Hence  $$\lim_j \frac{a_m(x/m^j)}{m^j} = 0$$

$$f(x) = x \lim_m \left(a_m(x) - \frac{a_m(x/m)}{m}\right)$$

Hence we have,
$$f(x) = x \lim_m \left(a_{m}(x) - \frac{a_{m}(x/m)}{m}\right) = x g(x)$$
$$g(x) = \lim_m \left(a_{m}(x) - \frac{a_{m}(x/m)}{m}\right) $$
With,
$$\lim_j \frac{a_m(x/m^j)}{m^j} = 0$$

$$\lim_j f(x/m^{j}) = \lim_j \frac{x}{m^j} \left(a_m(x/m^j) - \frac{a_m(x/m^{j+1})}{m}\right) = 0$$

So atleast $f(x)$ is continuous at $0$ w.r.t to sequence certain subsequences. An idea based on this is as follows:

One Idea is if  we show the behaviour in a neighbourhood of $x = 0$ then:
Let us assume $\sum_i f(x/m^i)$ converges absolutely, then, assume $f(x)$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $x = 0$ then,
$$f(x) = \sum_{i \geq 1} a_i x^i$$
Let $b_m(x) = x \times a_m(x)$ then,
$$\sum_j f(x/m^j) = b_m(x)$$
$$\sum_j \sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{a_i}{m^{ji}} x^i = b_m(x)$$
Now by the assumption that $\sum_i f(x/m^i)$ converges absolutely we interchange the order of summation,
$$\sum_{i \geq 1} \sum_j \frac{a_i}{m^{ji}} x^i = b_m(x)$$
$$\sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{a_i \times m^i}{m^i-1} x^i = b_m(x)$$
Hence we have an analytic expression for $b_m(x)$,
$$b_m(x) = \sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{a_i \times m^i}{m^i-1} x^i $$

The series converges for all points the original series $f(x) = \sum_{i \geq 1} a_i x^i$ conveges. Hence, both $f(x)$ and $b_m(x)$ has same region of convergence.

So knowing $b_m(x)$ with assumption its analytic for any $m$, we can determine $f(x)$ in the neighbourhood of $x = 0$.

If you put $m = 1$, $b_1(x)$ diverges i.e., its region of convergence is $x = 0$, hence the assumption that $\sum_i f(x/m^i)$ converges absolutely is not true for $m = 1$ and might be true for $m > 1$.

Hopefully you will find some of the above ideas useful or able apply or use it. Cheers !

Comment: why the fact that $a_m$ is increasing implies that it goes to infinity?

Comment: Thanks for point out. It actually converges. I modified my answer.

Comment: that is an even cooler result. I think $a_1=0$

Comment: I am confused now. No offense. 
Btw I assume $a_m = m - 1$ or around there ?

So $f(x/m) + f(x/m^2) + f(x/m^3) + ... = x/(m-1)$ or maybe $= f(x/(m-1)$ with the $m$ of maybe ...

But thanks for your interest and effort so far.

Comment: Updated the answer mike. Let me know if you still have an issue. I think i got ur point.

Comment: Hi! I replaced your `...` with `$\ldots$`, yielding $\ldots$—please feel free to revert if I've changed your intent anywhere. (MathJax won't kern `...` properly.)

Comment: Thanks Brian. I retained it.

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: It is not so clear to me how you go from $f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) +f(x/4) +f(x/5) + ...$ to things like $f(x) + f(x/m) + f(x/m^2)+f(x/m^3) + ...$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be a positive integer.

I considered thinking about estimating

$$\pi(x) + \pi(x/2) + \pi(x/3) + ... $$

The idea is simple.

we take primes $p_i < x$.

and we take $2 p_i < x$

and in general

$$n p_i < x $$

Then we naively expect all numbers between $1$ and $ x $ to be of these forms.

Hence the unions of $ n p_i$ should give about $x-1$.

However consider say $6 = 2*3$ and $35 = 5*7$.

$6$ is both of the form $ 2 p_i $ and $ 3 p_i $.
Similar for $35$ ; $ 5 p_i$ and $ 7 p_i$.

So it appears

$$\pi(x) + \pi(x/2) + \pi(x/3) + ... = \sum_1^x fact(i) = T(x)$$

where $fact(x)$ is the number of factorizations of $x$

Since

$$f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + ... = x$$

This implies (even without conjecture $A$ but obviously with conjecture $A$)

$$ \pi(R(x) - 1) < f(x) < \pi(x+1) $$

Where $R(x)$ is the functional inverse of $T(x)$

Based on the average number of factorizations for a random $x$, $R(x)$ has as asymptotic $\frac{x}{\ln(\ln(x))}$,

therefore

$$f(x) = \frac{\pi(x)}{\ln(\ln(x))}$$

is a good asymptotic.

This implies the limit from the OP is not true.
What was probably the reason the idea got abandonned.

As for getting better estimates I see two routes at the moment:

1. Improve the estimate of $R$ or $T$.
2. Use the estimate for $f(x)$ together with the ratio's $\pi(x/m)/f(x/m)$ and the functional equation,
   and repeat that idea for a sequence of increasing improved asymptotics.

( The previous answer was wrong and I will delete it )