# $t(x) - t(x/2) + t(x/3) - t(x/4) + ... = 0$ implies $t(x) + t(x/2)+t(x/3)+t(x/4) = C x$?

Tags: functional-equations, reverse-math, alternating-expression

Inspired by this mysterious function :

[$f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + f(x/4) + ... = x$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{\pi(n)} = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724917/fx-fx-2-fx-3-fx-4-x-and-lim-n-to-infty-fracfn)

I started to wonder since the alternating sum equals zero :

$$f(x) - f(x/2) + f(x/3) - f(x/4) + ... = 0$$

Do we have for every solution

$$t(x) - t(x/2) + t(x/3) - t(x/4) + ... = 0$$

the implication

$$t(x) + t(x/2)+t(x/3)+t(x/4) = C x$$

For some constant $C$ ??

Comment: http://www.math.columbia.edu/~goldfeld/ErdosSelbergDispute.pdf
seems to have a similar idea on page 8 but with an integral instead of sum.
So I am getting uncertain of the claim.

Comment: see : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4745073/about-a-counterexample-for-an-integral-functional-equation-in-number-theory