# About a counterexample for an integral-functional equation in number theory.

Tags: number-theory, examples-counterexamples, functional-equations, integral-equations

I was reading

[http://www.math.columbia.edu/~goldfeld/ErdosSelbergDispute.pdf](http://www.math.columbia.edu/%7Egoldfeld/ErdosSelbergDispute.pdf)

How did the counterexample for the equation on page 8 look like ??

Specificly :

(quote)

“Tur´an’s lecture (probably a quite informal thing considering the small
group) could not have been later than July 14, since it was before my
return. Straus has speeded up events; Erd˝os told me he was trying to
prove pn+1
pn → 1 on July 15. He told me he had a proof only late on July
16 or possibly earlier the next day. Straus’ quote is also clearly wrong for
the following reasons; first, I needed more than just pn+1
pn → 1 for my first
proof of the PNT, second, I only saw how to do it on Sunday, July 18.
It is true, however, as Erd˝os’ and Straus’ stories indicate, that when I first
was told by Erd˝os that he was trying to prove pn+1
pn → 1 from my formula,
I tried to discourage him, by saying that I doubted whether the formula
alone implied these things. I also said I had constructed a counterexample
showing that the relation in the form

$$f(x) \ln(x) + \int_1^x f(\frac{x}{t}) d f(t) = 2 x \ln(x) + (O(x)) $$

does not imply $f(x)$ is close to $x$.

(end quote)

Note: it is not clear to me and others what is meant by " close " here. I just copied a quote, if anyone knows I would love to know.

Comment: For the sake of being self-contained, please include relevant equation in your thread.

Comment: @Akira done more or less.

Answer (score -1):

What about $f(t)=t+ct^{1-\delta}$ for any small positive $\delta$? Of course, I don’t know what “is close to” means. Can you specify?

Comment: I think it is meant that $f(x) - x < 1$ But I am not sure. I just read the link that I posted in the OP and I got confused.

Comment: Well, as long as it doesn’t mean $f(t)-t = o(t)$. That seems harder …

Comment: @it might ... It was said that it was a surprise so ... it might have

Comment: Well, it’s up to the questioner to specify exactly what the question is.

Comment: true, but it seems like a semi-famous problem so I assumed everyone knows the details ...

Comment: That is erroneous on your part. In particular, *you* are the one posting the question and *you* clearly do not know the details. And nor do I. As it stands, my answer seems perfectly fine.

Comment: yes I do not know the full details. I wish someone here did. Note that I did not downvote you.

Comment: Yes, I wish the downvoter would make a positive contribution to the question or answer.