# $f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + ... = x$ and conjecture A : $\pi(x/a) > \frac{\pi(x)}{a}$

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers, conjectures

Consider $f(x)$ :

[$f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + f(x/4) + ... = x$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{\pi(n)} = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724917/fx-fx-2-fx-3-fx-4-x-and-lim-n-to-infty-fracfn)

and the edit that contains conjecture A :

$$\pi(x/a) > \frac{\pi(x)}{a}$$

Is there a name for conjecture A ?

Is there a proof or good argument ?

Any references or so ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a "solid ground" for a proof ...

From the [Dusart's result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Non-asymptotic_bounds_on_the_prime-counting_function), for $\forall x \ge 60184$ we have
$$\frac{x}{\log{x}}<\frac{x}{\log{x}-1} < \pi(x) <\frac{x}{\log{x} - 1.1}$$

Now, $\forall a \ge e^{1.1}$ and $a<x$ we have
$$\pi(x) <\frac{x}{\log{x} - 1.1}<\frac{x}{\log{x} - \log{a}}=a\cdot\frac{\frac{x}{a}}{\log{\frac{x}{a}}}$$
or
$$\frac{\pi(x)}{a}<\frac{\frac{x}{a}}{\log{\frac{x}{a}}}<\pi\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)$$

A computer program could check the remaining $\forall x < 60184$.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about Dusart myself. But the result is nontrivial. I assume a simpler proof exists. Or does this result imply Dusart's result ? That would make it equally hard as Dusart I assume.  Im still looking for a name. Anyway +1

Comment: I think the remaining ones follow from the numerical tests of the stronger Hardy-Littlewood ? somewhere ...

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but maybe useful :

if

$$\pi(x/a) > \frac{\pi(x)}{a}$$

and

$$\pi(x/b) > \frac{\pi(x)}{b}$$

then

$$\pi(\frac{x}{ab}) > \frac{\pi(x)}{ab}$$

This might simplify the proof.