# Asymptotics for $f(x)$ such that $f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + f(x/4) + ... = x$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, functional-equations, functional-inequalities

Consider

$$f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + f(x/4) + ... = x$$

$$f(n) < \pi(n+1)$$

Where $\pi$ is the prime counting function and that inequality follows for instance from these here

[$f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + ... = x$ and conjecture A : $\pi(x/a) > \frac{\pi(x)}{a}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728147/fx-fx-2-fx-3-x-and-conjecture-a-pix-a-frac-pix)

[$f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + f(x/4) + ... = x$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{\pi(n)} = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724917/fx-fx-2-fx-3-fx-4-x-and-lim-n-to-infty-fracfn)

Now the question here is simple.
What is a good asymptotic for $f(x)$ ? In particular for large (positive) $x$ ?

Maybe something like

$$\frac{x}{\ln(x) + A \sqrt{\ln(x)}+B}$$

Or

$$\frac{x}{\ln(x) + C \ln\ln(x)-1} $$

For some constants $A,B$ or $C$ ?

(The second estimate was given elsewhere(outside of MSE and MO) as a guess).

Comment: What does that infinite sum even mean? For example, what if $x=0$? What are the domain and codomain of $f$, actually?

Comment: @Servaes the context is on the reals or integers , not complex numbers. There is some freedom in defining things yes.  That does not pose a big problem. The estimates will not be affected much for small deviations in definition.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to define $f$ only on the integers, as then the sum is undefined for all $x$. I honestly don't know how to make sense of the expression
$$f(0)+f(0)+f(0)+\ldots=0.$$
Should I take it to mean $f(0)=0$? Or is $f$ not defined at $0$? Or something else? How does this mesh with the requirement that $f(0)<\pi(1)$?

Comment: yeah it is not so well defined for $x<2$

Comment: It is not clear to me that $f$ defines a function. Can you say some more words about this?

Comment: @hunter you mean continu ? Or uniquely defined ?

Comment: notice the added answer at second link

Comment: @mick, I mean, can you say some words for why there exists a function $f$ satisfying the given property? It is not obvious to me that such a function exists.

Comment: formally that is not so easy. I need to think about it. But if you look at the related links and sublinks you get an intuition. Notice $f(0) = 0 $ I was aware of the demand. That is why I waited so many years @hunter

Answer (score 1):

(the previous answer was wrong and I deleted it)

This is copy from the answer here : [$f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + f(x/4) + ... = x$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{\pi(n)} = 1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4724917/fx-fx-2-fx-3-fx-4-x-and-lim-n-to-infty-fracfn/4745052#4745052)

---

Let $x$ be a positive integer.

I considered thinking about estimating

$$\pi(x) + \pi(x/2) + \pi(x/3) + ... $$

The idea is simple.

we take primes $p_i < x$.

and we take $2 p_i < x$

and in general

$$n p_i < x $$

Then we naively expect all numbers between $1$ and $ x $ to be of these forms.

Hence the unions of $ n p_i$ should give about $x-1$.

However consider say $6 = 2*3$ and $35 = 5*7$.

$6$ is both of the form $ 2 p_i $ and $ 3 p_i $.
Similar for $35$ ; $ 5 p_i$ and $ 7 p_i$.

So it appears

$$\pi(x) + \pi(x/2) + \pi(x/3) + ... = \sum_1^x fact(i) = T(x)$$

where $fact(x)$ is the number of factorizations of $x$

Since

$$f(x) + f(x/2) + f(x/3) + ... = x$$

This implies (even without conjecture $A$ but obviously with conjecture $A$)

$$ \pi(R(x) - 1) < f(x) < \pi(x+1) $$

Where $R(x)$ is the functional inverse of $T(x)$

Based on the average number of factorizations for a random $x$, $R(x)$ has as asymptotic $\frac{x}{\ln(\ln(x))}$,

therefore

$$f(x) = \frac{\pi(x)}{\ln(\ln(x))}$$

is a good asymptotic.

This implies the limit from the OP is not true.
What was probably the reason the idea got abandonned.

As for getting better estimates I see two routes at the moment:

1. Improve the estimate of $R$ or $T$.
2. Use the estimate for $f(x)$ together with the ratio's $\pi(x/m)/f(x/m)$ and the functional equation,
   and repeat that idea for a sequence of increasing improved asymptotics.